# Images not being displayed in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I'm a noob to React and I'm trying to map over an array and display a bunch of images.
All my images are located under public/images folder.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { bagsTypes } from '@/const/types';
import Image from 'next/image';

function Hero({ bags }: { bags: bagsTypes[] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {bags.map((bag) => {
        return (
          <div key={bag.id}>
            <h1>{bag.name}</h1>
            <Image
              alt={`bag-${bag.id}`}
              height={150}
              width={100}
              src={`/images/${bag.image}`}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

```
import { bagsTypes } from './types';

const bags: bagsTypes[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'bag1', image: 'bag1.png' },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bag2',
    image: 'bag2.png',
  },
];

export default bags;
```

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22rzw.png)

Do I need to import the images somewhere?

Comment: What do you have when you console.log(bag.image) inside the map?

Comment: i think the problem is where you store bag1.png - is it inside `/public/images` dir?

Answer (score 1):

Src prop of **Image** tag provide an object not a string, u can do this

```
 <Image
  alt={`bag-${bag.id}`}
  height={150}
  width={100}
  src={{
      src: `/images/${bag.image}`,
      height: 150,
      width: 100
     }}
  />
```

Or u can use img tag

```
 <img
  alt={`bag-${bag.id}`}
  height={150}
  width={100}
  src={`/images/${bag.image}`}
 />
```

If u have any other problem check the paths of images

Comment: Not true. src is a string https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image